# Getting items from Amazon DynamoDB using 'where' condition

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How to get items from **dynamoDB** using '*where*' condition?

For example,

```
select 'names' from Employee where dept="billing"
```

(I want to get all the names from Employee table whose department is "billing")

How to write a query for this in Java code? Explained with example code is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Select-query could be something like that:

```
SELECT `names`  FROM `Employee` WHERE `dept` LIKE 'billing'
```

With some java stuff:

```
try {
        String url = "jdbc:msql://***.***.***.***:****/Demo";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT `names`  FROM `Employee` WHERE `dept` LIKE 'billing'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("names");
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I want the query for Amazon DynamoDB database.

Comment: Sorry my fault.. mybe this link help you more: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaQueryScanORMModelExample.html

Comment: With pleasure.. If i helped you, please accept my answer and have fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can search the Dynamo DB using the Primary Key (hash key) or a Composite key using (hash+range key)

If any day you are trying to search any attribute of an item you would have to do a complete `Scan` of the database which is pretty inefficient.

So, try to design your database in a way that you **DO NOT** end up doing `Scans` and encourage doing searches based on indexes for which Dynamo is designed.

For the original question : you may use `ProjectionExpression` for the searches.

For further reference - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Scan